# RVM installed ruby not found after restart of shell Ubuntu 16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed RVM and ruby and at first it seemed to work, but whenever I open a new shell tab or window only rvm can be found, not ruby.

Running `rvm -v` gives me a nice little output:

```
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

but running `ruby -v`, `gem -v` or `rails -v` gives me an error telling me to `apt-get install ruby/rails`.

I've installed rvm through the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I installed ruby like so:

```
rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
```

Rails was installed with the command:

```
gem install rails
```

---

### What I've tried:

I've checked my `.bashrc` `.bash_profile` and my `.profile` and it's set up nicely with the following:

`.bashrc` and `.profile` :

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

`.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

### What kinda works:

Running the line `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` allows `ruby`, `gem`, and `rails` to be found again, but you have to repeat this is every new tab or window.

## How can I fix so that `rvm` installed modules will work automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out everything is set up nicely and correct. If you have this issue it's an issue with your shell settings. **You need to set your profile to login shell**.

### How to set this in the standard terminal on Ubuntu's standard GUI

#### *(GNOME terminal Unity)*

Access your settings by going to the menu and pic `Terminal > Preferences`.

In the window that pops up, select `Profiles` in the tab menu. Pick if you want to create a new profile or edit the existing default one. In the window that comes up (it's the same regardless of your pic) go to the tab `Command` and enable `Run command as a login shell`.

Restart your terminal and you should find that your rvm commands are now working.

Comment: “Access your settings by going to the menu and pic `Terminal` > `Preferences`.”—there are many different terminals all around and this advise does not work for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. This answer refers to the standard terminal that comes with the ubuntu GUI (Unity I believe it's called). This answer is written by and for a beginner user of Ubuntu. I'll append this to the answer.

Comment: Appreciate it. It is “GNOME Terminal.”

Comment: Pleae, anybody can tell me. how i can setup this funcionallty for byobu terminal

Comment: Did you try to do the same thing? doesn't it have a menu when you hover next to the close, minimize and fullssceen buttons on the top bar?

Comment: WIndows user trying to set it this up for the first time on Ubuntu. Was about to slit my wrist. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

What about adding to your .profile or .bashrc

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.profile
```

EDIT

You need to call **source** from either *.profile* or *.bashrc* NOT .bash_profile

```
jperez@asus-kubuntu16:~$ grep bash_profile .profile                                                                                                                 
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
jperez@asus-kubuntu16:~$
```

Comment: You mean like `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` which was mentioned in the original question? The original question also states that adding it to `.profile` still caused the problem. Your answer will not fix the issue in the question which is that the shell doesn't even read that information by default.

Answer (score 1):

In Deepin Terminal run:
 `sudo nano ~/.config/deepin/deepin-terminal/config.conf`

and change **run_as_login_shell=false** to true

Answer (score -2):

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
> sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
> gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
> source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
> rvm install 2.3.1
> rvm use 2.3.1 --default
> ruby -v
```

Comment: Worked for me with running only:

> sudo apt-get update 

> sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev

> sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev